# how to read values in bean shell programming?

Tags: jquery, jmeter, beanshell

What is wrong with my code? The highlighted part is the ID of my field, but when i see the database, it shows "password" instead of the values inside the "password" ID. Any help?

thank you!!

[beanshellprogrammingpicture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPpqI.jpg)

Comment: It looks like you are inserting "password" as value, so the records will show password. Is that the question?

Comment: Post your code as text in your question rather than as an image...

Answer (score 0):

**but when i see the database, it shows "password" instead of the values inside the "password" ID** - yes it will show password only hence you're passing password only in your code.

```
stmt.setString(1,"password");
```

in beanshell programming you need to access the parameters like

```
String password = vars.get("password"); //fetching the password value and storing it in password variable
stmt.setString(1,password);
```